# How to read a JSON object in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am developing a service that receives a POST request with a JSON data packet. After receiving, the service needs to send this JSON object to another method where it needs to convert it to Pandas dataframe.

I know Pandas `read_json` method expects file. But I do now have a file and I do not want to write a file. How do I resolve this?

```
@app.route('/data/api/json',methods=['POST'])
def getData():
    content=jsonify(request.json)
    #return content
    process(content)

def process(jsonContent):
    test = pd.read_json(jsonContent) #this will NOT work
```

Comment: If it is already loaded as a python dictionary, use `pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on how your JSON is structured, so if none of the suggestions work please share a simple example of your JSON file. For files looking like

```
[{col1:foo, col2: bar},{col1:footwo, col2:bartwo}]
```

I usually use

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your string to a file-like buffer:

```
import io
test = pd.read_json(io.StringIO(jsonContent))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```